# Error installing PECL expect package for PHP on Mint

Tags: php, ubuntu, expect, linux-mint, pecl

Hello people of the internet

I am new to Linux.
I'm moving over from Windows.

I'm trying to install the PECL expect package for PHP: https://pecl.php.net/package/expect
I've followed the instructions on these pages.
But both give me errors, which I've details below:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php

```
$ cd extname
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
# make install
```

When I get to the ./configure, the last two lines in the terminal say:
checking specify path to Tcl needed by expect... yes, shared
checking for tcl version... configure: error: not found

I have Tcl installed, and it's the latest version.

When I try the make command it says:
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I can't find a makefile, only a Makefile.global, Makefile.fragments, and Makefile.objects

https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.pear.php
sudo pecl install expect

The last line in the terminal say:
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/expect/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed

I looked on the net, and installed every dependency that others recommended, but it still doesn't work.
I've downloaded so many dependencies now, that my machine is probably not safe anymore...

Does anybody know what else I need to do to install the package?

I'm using Linux Mint 19.3.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the `tcl-dev` package?

Comment: No, I didn't, so thanks for that.
That's very helpful.

Now there is another error.
I used command
`sudo pecl install expect`
and received the following result:

In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/expect/expect.c:21:0:
/tmp/pear/temp/expect/php_expect.h:33:10: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <tcl.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:194: recipe for target 'expect.lo' failed
make: *** [expect.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

It seems that tcl.h is missing.
Any idea how to correct that?

Comment: I installed tk-dev as well.

Comment: I searched my laptop and I found tcl.h in two locations: 
/usr/include/tcl8.6 and 
/usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl=private/generic

Comment: This is a guess: in the ./configure step, you may need to specify something like `--with-tcl=/usr/include/tcl8.6` or something like that.

Comment: Glenn, thanks for your help. You have steered me in the right direct. I had to install package tcl-expect-dev. On another note: linux is hard! I can't believe how much stuff you have to figure out to install something. Forgive me for saying this, but I get why Bill is wealthy... Microsoft is user friendly. Anyway, that is my rant. I think you kind sir for your time and wisdom.